# Ambiguous call to constructor "super(null)" in java.net.DatagramSocket?

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I am extending the class `Java.net.DatagramSocket` and giving the subclass its own constructor. The constructor for my new class, `UDP_Socket`, is as follows

```
private UDP_Socket(int port) throws IOException {
    super(null); // Creates an unbound socket.
    super.setReuseAddress(true); // You set reuse before binding.
    super.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port)); // finally, bind
}
```

The only problem is on the line `super(null)`, I am getting `ambiguous reference to both constructor DatagramSocket(DatagramSocketImpl) and DatagramSocket(SocketAddress)`. I need the `super(null)` line to create an unbound socket and I believe that I am supposed to set the reuse address socket option before binding. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you call `super(null)` is valid parameter to both `DatagramSocket(DatagramSocketImpl)` and `DatagramSocket(SocketAddress)`.

So, the compiler is confused. You can call only one of the constructors.

Use,

```
super((DatagramSocketImpl) null);
```

or,

```
super((SocketAddress) null);
```

depending on which constructor you want to call.

Comment: Well you would hardly want a null `DatagramSocketImpl`.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
ambiguous reference to both constructor DatagramSocket(DatagramSocketImpl) and DatagramSocket(SocketAddress)
```

Is telling you that `null` can reference `(DatagramSocketImpl) null` or `(SocketAddress) null` thus making it ambiguous.

You must explicitly call one of the two constructors

```
 // super((DatagramSocketImpl) null)
 super((SocketAddress) null)
```

or have your constructor require that

```
private UDP_Socket(int port, SocketAddress addr) throws IOException {
    super(addr);
```

**Edit:**

Code from: [Class DatagramSocket](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html)

```
 private DatagramSocket getDatagramSocket (int port) {
    DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null);
    s.setReuseAddress(true);
    s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

    return s;
 }
```

Comment: Yea thats totally legal in Java

Comment: The "super();" call won't work because the default constructor automatically bind the socket without allowing me to set any other socket options.

Comment: see my edit Just call the constructor that corresponds to the port

Comment: You can't do that because if you used that constructor on the first line you wouldn't be able to call "super.setReuseAddress(true)". "super.setReuseAddress(true)" only works after a call to the null constructor and before a binding call.

Comment: If `super(null)` is throwing ambiguous error, then `new DatagramSocket(null)` would also throw the same. How will that help?

Comment: Lol thats what the link is for, `protected DatagramSocket(DatagramSocketImpl impl)` is protected thus making it invisible to the world which leaves you with one constructor

Comment: @Codebender the exact code is in the link if you follow it

Comment: The default constructor will allocate a random port. Not a solution. The code you've quoted is curious, as the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean)) clearly states "When a `DatagramSocket` is created the initial setting of SO_REUSEADDR is disabled.".

Comment: Removed the default constructor solution. So what the OP is trying to do won't work? bc I pretty sure I gave all possible solutions IMHO